# How can i remove an email from an string using a String class>

Tags: java, regex, string, class, java-home

Which string class is to use when we want to remove an email address from a string.

need help and i am a newbie in java.

thanks

Comment: what do you mean, like get "email@example.com" from "my email address is email@example.com and my phone number is 555-123-4567"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `String` class. It has a few methods which are helpful, such as [replaceAll](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), and replaceFirst.

You'll need a good regular expression to capture the email address part of the String. [This](http://www.zparacha.com/ultimate-java-regular-expression-to-validate-email-address/) might be helpful.